# Creating a hyperlinked image with onclick event in RowDataBound

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the below Colmn in a Gridview.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <a href="AddNote.aspx" onclick="return popitup('AddNote.aspx?Account=<%# Eval("AccountID") %>&ID=<%# Eval("Invoice ID") %>')"><img src="Images/NoteIcons/note_add.png" height="16" width="16" /></a>
</ItemTemplate>
```

I want it it to only show based on a value coming from the databind.

So I removed the itemtemplate code and in Gridview_RowDataBound I added the following code.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      if (e.Row.Cells[10].Text != "1")
            {
                //Code to display hyperlink and image
            }    
    }
```

Do I need to switch this to a image button? I'm not sure how I can get the link, onclick and image to show up all together. I tried with Hyperlink newHyperlink =  new HyperLink(); but I don't see the property to set an onclick event.

Any help with dynamically building this column when the text =! 1?

Thank you.

Comment: for starters you can change the anchor tag to an asp:Hyperlink such that the Visible attribute is available to you in the RowDataBound event

Comment: or...you can modify the select statement and add a boolean display field that is calculated sql side based on your display criteria and used the Eval in your markup inside the template such that `<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("display") %>' ><img src="yada yada yada" /></asp:HyperLink>` means something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing something like this

```
ImageButton btn= new ImageButton();
btn.ImageUrl="Images/NoteIcons/note_add.png";
btn.Attributes.Add("onClientClick", "YourJavaScriptFunction();");
e.Row.Cells[10].Controls.Add(btn);
```

Comment: How do I wrap the hyperlink onclick event around the button?